# Crawling a web site using Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-crawler

For my first crawling program, I plan to do the following:

1. Open the following URL using Selenium: http://www.google.com/
2. collect all relevant links
3. On the resulting page, enumerate all the http links which are present and storem them in a csv.
4. Go back to step 2, but click the next one

How can I get started? (I'm on Python 2.6.6).

Comment: Selenium usage for this site is overkill. Site doesn't have any dynamical (ajax) content. If it's your first task, try [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) There are samples in documentation

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) library, finding links on a page is very easy and there are examples on StackOverflow already.

Comment: thanks every one.your suggestion really helped me.

Comment: i used this BeautifulSoup library and crawled the below link

Comment: Take a look at Python's re library (for regular expressions), you can use it to match URLs meeting your criteria.

Answer (score 1):

IMO, [lxml](http://lxml.de/) is much easier to use and has a pythonic API. Look [here](http://ms4py.org/2010/4/10/python-search-engine-crawler-part-1/) for an example with detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered contacting the folks at Cars.com if your goal is just to get the data? They might be able to give a you a feed or API access, assuming your end goal is to get the data and not just develop the crawling program.